# Simple Ratio of selected stock vs the SPX

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

sorry for the stupid question, but I am struggling to get a fairly simple code done.

I am trying to calculate the ratio of the current active stock divided by the SPX (so close[stock] / close [SPX].For some reason, I get "1" as a result an I suspect, it has to do with the fact that call "SPX".

```
//@version=5    
indicator("", "", true)

SPX = input.source(close, "SPX")    
Ratio = close / SPX

plot(Ratio)
```

The SPX is the constant here.

For some reason, I get "1" as a result an I suspect, it has to do with the fact that call "SPX".

```
//@version=5
indicator("", "", true)

SPX = input.source(close, "SPX")
Ratio = close / SPX

plot(Ratio)
```

What changes must I do`?

Answer (score 0):

With `SPX = input.source(close, "SPX")` you just defining a source input titled SPX. It does not give you the close price of SPX.

You need to use the `request.security()` function to get the close price of SPX.

Example to get the close price of IBM from NYSE:

```
//@version=5
pindicator("Example security 1", overlay=true)
ibm_15 = request.security("NYSE:IBM", "15", close)
plot(ibm_15)
```

You can read more about the security function from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html).